# Problem writting curly braces { and } to browser in RPG-CGI (AS/400)

Tags: javascript, cgi, ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am using  **QtmhWrStout** API(in **AS/400 SERVER**) using **RPGLE** language to write the HTML code for my display page to the browser(client-side). My HTML code is embedded in my RPG-CGI program (.pgm), I have kept a java-script function in that HTML code that is to be executed in clients' browser. But when that page is displayed in browser...,page source contains some symbols like **ä** for **{** and **ü** for **}** .For this reason the events can not call the java-script function.Java-script error is shown.

**HTML Page-source generated by my rpgle progrm in clients' browser:**

```
<html> <head>
<title>ERP!!Enter Product Details</title>    
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
function crt(spnid,elmnm,val)    
ä
   var cat=document.getElementById(spnid);
   cat.innerHTML="";    
   if(val=="new")
   ä
      var elm=document.createElement("input");    
      elm.setAttribute("type","text");
      elm.setAttribute("name",elmnm);
      cat.appendChild(elm);
   ü
 ü
 </SCRIPT>
 </head>

<body bgcolor="lightblue">
<form action="sss" method="post">    
<table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" style="width: 80%">
<tbody><tr><td><table align="center" border="0"><caption>    
<strong>Insert Product Details</strong></caption><tbody><tr>    
<td style="text-align: right">Product Category</td>
```

I tried to use the hex code but still not happenning......
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKDrw.png

As I am a new learner of this RPGLE(AS/400)...Pease help me out to use java-script in PGM generated html file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What CCSID is your job running under?  37?

Have you tried setting the doctype on the content you are delivering?

Try using the contenttype meta variable?

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"/>`

or

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>`

Comment: I have tried this <meta tag but the whole page is getting full of symbols.......no form display....          Symbols are like....     L����n %L����n %L�����nŕ���@�������@ą�����La�����n %L������@��������~����������n %��������@���M�����k��

Comment: @Nirmal, that means that character set conversion is disabled, and you need to do it yourself.  This may end up being VERY painful...

Comment: @Nirmal Thorbjørn is correct ... you should set a specific CCSID so that character trans-coding takes place.